# How can I join a has_many association with a scope in Active Record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, scope, associations

This is my association and scope setup:

```
has_many    :owned_products

has_many    :owned_lessons, :through => :owned_products, :source => :lesson, :conditions => "owned_products.product_type = 'Lesson'"

scope :active_purchase_scope, lambda {
    where('owned_products.created_at' => (Date.today - CONFIG['downloads']['time_window'].days)..(Date.today)).order('owned_products.created_at DESC')
}

def active_lessons 
    owned_lessons.active_purchase_scope
end
```

This is the error I get:

```
ruby-1.8.7-p334 :005 > User.find_by_username('joeblow').active_lessons
NoMethodError: undefined method `active_purchase_scope' for #<User:0x1051a26c8>
```

da

Answer (score 4):

A `scope` can be treated as a class method and an `association` can be treated as an instance method. In your code sample, the `owned_lessons` method returns an array object. You can't call `active_purchase_scope` on the array object (or User object for that matter) as the scope can only be invoked on the Model class (i.e. in your case `User.active_purchase_scope`)

You can address this issue by adding the scope on the `Lesson` model

```
class Lesson
  has_many    :owned_products

  scope :active_purchase_scope, lambda {
    include(::owned_products).where('owned_products.created_at' => 
          (Date.today - CONFIG['downloads']['time_window'].days)..(Date.today)).
            order('owned_products.created_at DESC')
  }

end
```

And rewrite the User class as follows:

```
class User

  has_many    :owned_products

  has_many    :owned_lessons, :through => :owned_products, :source => :lesson, 
                 :conditions => "owned_products.product_type = 'Lesson'"


  def active_lessons 
    owned_lessons.active_purchase_scope
  end

end
```

The `owned_lessons` returns an anonymous scope on the `Lesson` model, hence we can chain it with the scope `active_purchase_scope` from the same model.

Comment: I understood why this wasn't working (because of the Array class), but I still don't know how to abstract the active_purchase_scope, because all products will need to use this, not just Lesson. At the moment my product Models don't inherit from anything. Should I try to make a Product model that all products inherit from (this might really confuse things, bucause I have product_id in the join tables) or could I accomplish the same thing via a mixin?